# Retrieve last record of sqlite database

Tags: android

```
 public class PlaceCallActivity extends BaseActivity {
    private static final String SELECT_SQL = "SELECT * FROM numbers";
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             opendatabase();
     c = db.rawQuery(SELECT_SQL, null);
            c.moveToLast();
        userNo.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("number")));
        }
    public void opendatabase(){
            db=openOrCreateDatabase("NumberDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
 }
```

I want to set text of the last retrieve data from column of "number"
At Runtime i recieved the following error :

```
CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 0
```

The error is at line where i am setting the text.

**i.e.** "userNo.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("number")));"

Comment: Will u debug and check what is the value of c.getColumnIndex("number") ?

Comment: i guess the problem is there is no data found which you are requesting.

Comment: Ok so there is no inserted data? which i am doing in another activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because there is no data in cursor, before fetching data from cursor you have to first check it's count.

```
if(c.getCount()!=0)
{
    if(c.moveToLast())
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class PlaceCallActivity extends BaseActivity {
private static final String SELECT_SQL = "SELECT * FROM numbers";
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         opendatabase();
 c = db.rawQuery(SELECT_SQL, null);
   if(c.getCount()>0)
      {
        c.moveToLast();
    userNo.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("number")));
  }  
  }
public void opendatabase(){
        db=openOrCreateDatabase("NumberDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
}
```

Comment: I think you almost did it but i am suffering from more problem i guess by doing above thing it pass on since i am creating login using shared preferences and using this even if i delete my app it still take or pass on to another activity without coming to first where i am inserting data. So it is taking null values to this PlaceCallActivity so i did android:allowBackup="false"

Comment: then i get this Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@allowBackup value=(false) from AndroidManifest.xml:21:13-40
   is also present at [com.msg91.sendotp.library:library:2.7] AndroidManifest.xml:12:9-35 value=(true).
   Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:allowBackup"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:19:5-50:19 to override.

Comment: @SameerKhan1406 then do what the message suggests and try add 'tools:replace="android:allowBackup"' in manifest

Comment: First i am creating login where i am using shared preferences so that login screen comes only once and in that same activity i am insereting data too.
Then there is another activity where i am doing a lot more heavylifting and since second activity need that number which i inserted therefore i am trying to retrieve the last inserted number from my database which i created in login activity

Comment: I seriously don't know as soon as i add pref.isloggedin() condition it starts with next activity skipping the login screen and the number which i am setting as text is blank cause it never was inserted so it doesn't have anything inside its database

Comment: if you could share your skype id i can connect you on saturday and show you my part code then take a look

Comment: @Raghavendra and thanks to you for partly helping me i did as it suggested now i guess there is no backup

Comment: @RushiAyyappa skype or whatever you could suggest or comfortable with